# HLS Live streaming with re-encoding

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, http-live-streaming

I come to a technical problem and I need you.

Situation data:

- I record the screen as well as 1 to 2 audio tracks (microphone and speaker).
- These three recordings are done separately (it could be mixed but I don't prefer) and every 10s (this is configurable), I send the chunk of recorded data to my backend. We, therefore, have 2 to 3 chunks sent every 10s.
- These data chunks are interdependent. Example: The 1st video chunk starts with the headers and a keyframe. The second chunk can be in the middle of a frame. It's like having the entire video and doing a random one-bit split.
- The video stream is in h264 in a WebM container. I don't have a lot of control over it.
- The audio stream is in opus in a WebM container. I can't use aac directly, nor do I have much control.
- Given the reality, the server may be restarted randomly (crash, update, scaled, ...). It doesn't happen often (4 times a week). In addition, the customer can, once the recording ends on his side, close the application or his computer. This will prevent the end of the recording from being sent. Once it reconnects, the missing data chunks are sent. This, therefore, prevents the use of a "live" stream on the backend side.

Goals :

- Store video and audio as it is received on the server in cloud storage.
- Be able to start playing the video/audio even when the upload has not finished (so in a live stream)
- As soon as the last chunks have been received on the server, I want the entire video to be already available in VoD (Video On Demand) with as little delay as possible.
- Everything must be distributed with the audios in AAC. The audios can be mixed or not, and mixed or not with the video.

Current and blocking solution:
The most promising solution I have seen is using HLS to support the Live and VoD mode that I need. It would also bring a lot of optimization possibilities for the future.

Video isn't a problem in this context, here's what I do:

1. Every time I get a data chunk, I append it to a screen.webm file.
2. Then I spit the file with ffmpeg
   ffmpeg -ss {total_duration_in_storage} -i screen.webm -c: v copy -f hls -hls_time 8 -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8
3. I ignore the last file unless it's the last chunk.
4. I upload all the files to the cloud storage along with a newly updated output.m3u8 with the new file information.

Note: total_duration_in_storage corresponds to the time already uploaded
on cloud storage. So the sum of the parts presents in the last output.m3u8.

Note 2: I ignore the last file in point 3 because it allows me to have keyframes in each song of my playlist and therefore to be able to use a seeking which allows segmenting only the parts necessary for each new chunk.

My problem is with the audio. I can use the same method and it works fine, I don't re-encode. But I need to re-encode in aac to be compatible with HLS but also with Safari.
If I re-encode only the new chunks that arrive, there is an auditory glitch

The only possible avenue I have found is to re-encode and segment all the files each time a new chunk comes along. This will be problematic for long recordings (multiple hours).

Do you have any solutions for this problem or another way to achieve my goal?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, I handle this by using a MediaRecorder client-side, H.264 video and Opus audio in WebM (well, Matroska anyway), and then transcoding the audio to AAC server-side.  Things stay in-sync thanks to MediaRecorder.

Comment: Hi Brad,

So you transcoded in real-time while the file is uploaded? But if your server crash, you need to upload again from scratch, I'm right?